# IE conditional comments not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why the following code download BOTH `2.0.2` and `1.9.1` in IE8? (actually it's IE9 but in IE8 browser mode)

I am not so sure on the syntax, just copy/paste it from somewhere. But it works as expect on Firefox (only download 2.0.2) and IE9 (only download 2.0.2 as well), but on IE8 (again, IE9 in IE8 browser mode) both files get downloaded.

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
</head>
```

BONUS question:
What's the complication if both jquery files are downloaded?

Comment: Have you noticed your syntax is different for the two different blocks? The syntax highlighting that SO does might also help you find the answer...

Comment: I did try other syntax, but this one at least partially works. Others don't. If you are sure about the right syntax, plz paste it in answer, thx

Answer (score 1):

The correct code according to MS is:

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<![if gte IE 9]>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<![endif]>
</head>
```

As you can see the first block is the same. The second block has had some syntax removed that was unnecessary and almost certainly what was confusing things. Additionally it uses the "downlevel-revealed" syntax of conditional comments which will display on everything that doesn't recognise this conditional comment syntax.

Searching for "internet explorer conditional comments" was all that was needed to find this definitive help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

On further investigation your original code looks like it was based on that given in http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/ . I would guess therefore that this should work and therefore your problems are more likely coming from your rather interesting test environment which is both IE8 and IE9 at the same time.

Comment: Fixed. I missed the FF comments in your post.

Comment: I tried your code but nothing changes at ll. Firefox and IE9 work as expect. IE8 still download both files

Comment: Maybe problem is "IE9 in IE8 browser mode"? Maybe if I just use a real IE8 and problem goes away?

Comment: I did wonder about that. I would expect it to do one or the other (ie only one of `lt IE 9` or `gte IE 9` is true but its not a great way of testing. Especially since although the rendering is IE 8 mode I don't know if the script engine it uses is downgraded too...